# Scrolling to a different positions with ScrollView

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to sync two Scrollviews together. I have the position of the first ScrollView in a state. How can I set the position of the second ScrollView to match the position of the first Scrollview.

Comment: Did you tried `firstScrollview.contentOffset = secondScrollview.contentOffset` ?

Comment: No I did not but it seems like it could solve my issue. Where exactly would I put that so that it happens every time the screen is scrolled?

Comment: Derek already provided exact answer. Im sure it will fit for ios/swift, don't know about react-native

Comment: I am not sure if react-native has the same functionality. I do not think this method will work for me. Thanks for trying

Comment: Probably this: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#onscroll + usage of offset will do the work ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `scrollTo`.

Get your second ScrollView by `ref` and then `secondScrollView.scrollTo(this.state.firstScrollViewPosition)`

Answer (score 2):

You would need to utilize the delegate method `scrollViewDidScroll` in your controller.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619392-scrollviewdidscroll?changes=_6

```
var firstScrollView = UIScrollView()    
var secondScrollView = UIScrollView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    firstScrollView.delegate = self
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    // Set the content position of the second scroll view
    secondScrollView.contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
}
```

Edit:

The above solution is a more native solution.  Thanks [Michal Gorzalczany](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9865234/michal-gorzalczany) for adding the react link. http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#onscroll.

Comment: and for react- native probably this: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#onscroll

Comment: Whoops!  I didn't see the react tags in the question.  I'll leave this answer here in case someone who isn't using react comes across this question.